# Android Studio doesn't show exception stack trace

Tags: android, android-studio

This is driving me nuts. No exception is thrown when I debug my app it just stops out of the blue. The only workaround I have found so far is to put a huge try-catch block in order to see the exception that caused the crash, but this is really not a solution. I have already tried to kill and restart adb server and I don't use Google Analytics so I can't disable the exception tracker, as it's suggested in other questions here in stackoverfow. My log level is set to debug, and I don't have any filters in my stack. I think this has something to do with Android Studio but I can't figure it out.

Comment: are you using a real device to test your applications?

Comment: Yeah i use my mobile phone for debugging

Comment: I had the same problem...I post you the solution

Comment: try firebase crash , it helped me when i had this problem

Comment: I am using mobile center crash reports but the fact is that not the whole trace is shown and I have to wait about a minute for it to be shown. Thx anyway I will try it :)

Comment: Check the MinSDK. There is a possiblity that the MinSDK is higher than the API version of the phone.

Comment: No it's not something like that. It wouldn't run this way. Now it runs but if it crashes it doesn't show the stacktrace

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a real device, probably the logging is disabled from the OS.

Open the dialer e type this code *#*#2846579#*#*.

Go to *Background Settings* **>** *LOG Settings* and check the logging option you need.

Reboot the phone.

Comment: It definetely shows a lot more things but I activated everything and I ended up having a ton of errors in my log. Which one should I keep?

Comment: Still not getting a stacktrace :/

Comment: Mmm strange..try to use an emulator. If the logcat works we can exclude a misconfiguration of the ide

Comment: I think that's where I'm going to end up. Anyway luckily I found the exception so I will keep coding. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check:

- Are you working on Android Studio with Canary version?
- Check your Android Studio is targeting your device on debug mode.
- Try to invalidate the cache and restart to your studio Under File > Invalidate Caches/Restart (this has helped me).

Comment: How to check the first one? As for the other my device is targetted as for you other suggestion I will try it and inform you if it worked out.

Comment: This is the version you have installed.
also, you can check on Android Studio in the title of the environment.
something like Android Studio 3 Canary 7

Comment: if all this suggestion not work try to open avd (emulator) and check if you get exception on stack trace